# Test LED before starting code

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

Can't quite find exactly what I am looking for.

I've written the following code:

```
    /*
  Traffic Lights
  Turns on an LED on in a predetermined sequence - Red, Red Amber, Green, Amber, Red.

  This example code is in the public domain.
 */

// determine the colours and the pins that they are connected to
int green = 12; //green
int amber = 8; //amber
int red = 4; //red

// the setup routine runs once when you press reset:
void setup() 
{                
  // initialize the digital pins as an output.
  pinMode(green, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(amber, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(red, OUTPUT);
}

// the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(red, HIGH); //red on
  delay(1250);
  digitalWrite(amber, HIGH); //red amber on
  delay(1250);
  digitalWrite(red, LOW);
  digitalWrite(amber, LOW); //red amber off
  delay(250);
  digitalWrite(green, HIGH); //green on
  delay(1250);
  digitalWrite(green, LOW); //green off
  delay(250);
  digitalWrite(amber, HIGH); //amber on
  delay(1250);
  digitalWrite(amber, LOW); //amber off
  delay(250);
  digitalWrite(red, HIGH); //red on
  delay(1250);


}
```

And am very much a n00b to Arduino; a developer friend of mine is trying to make me 'test' everything before my code works (TDD approach) and my idea is to switch all of the lights on at the same time at the beginning; pretty simple to do that with a little `'digitalWrite(green, HIGH);` for example.  However, I don't want it to loop, I just want them to come on one time only for about 2 seconds to show that they are working, and then step into the loop.

Can anyone help at all?

Comment: You even have the comments right there...: _// the setup routine runs once_

Comment: Have you tried putting the code to switch all the lights on for 2 seconds at the end of the setup() method?  Since that method is only executed once, wouldn't that work?

Comment: Just before you typed your reply I put this together.  I figured that if it is in the 'setup' it should work:

//test that the pins are all working
  {
  digitalWrite(red, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(amber, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(green, HIGH);
  delay(2500);
  digitalWrite(red, LOW);
  digitalWrite(amber, LOW);
  digitalWrite(green, LOW);
  }

Comment: that should do it. Did it?

Comment: It certainly did - amazing what you can do when you realise you know the stuff, thanks for your help though :)

Answer (score 1):

Just do it in your Setup function! Remember that setup runs exactly once when your Arduino is powered on (or reset), then the loop function is called until the device is powered off.

I would try the following snippet:

```
void setup() 
{                
  // initialize the digital pins as an output.
  pinMode(green, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(amber, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(red, OUTPUT);
  //Turn the pins on to check your wiring
  digitalWrite(green, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(amber, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(red, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(green, LOW);
  digitalWrite(amber, LOW);
  digitalWrite(red, LOW);
}
```

EDIT: It might also be worthwhile to surround the debug code in an ifdef with:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
...
#endif
```

EDIT: For Clarification (in response to comment):

```
#ifdef DEBUG
  digitalWrite(green, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(amber, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(red, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(green, LOW);
  digitalWrite(amber, LOW);
  digitalWrite(red, LOW);
#endif
```

That way, you can keep the debug code in, and "turn it off" when you're no longer debugging.

Comment: Question - why would I pop the code into the ifdef??

Comment: @Boltz101 the ifdef statement will allow you to compile your code differently for debugging purposes by using a flag at compile time.